# CSS to make background image stay in place even with different browser size

Tags: html, css

I have a `CSS` background image, but when I resize by browser to go bigger the image moves to the left. How do I keep the image in the same place even when the browser resizes? My code (so far) is:

```
.home-top {
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url('../assets/images/home-2x.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: -75px -600px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}
```

Any idea's?

Comment: Try adding `background-size: cover;`?

Comment: That just makes the image larger and covers the entire area.

Comment: Have you tried setting the background size to `contain`?

Comment: `contain` did not work

Comment: make background-position: center;

Comment: i feel like `background-position` property could be a value relative to the div – i.e `left center` https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp

Comment: Why do you have `background-position: -75px -600px`?

Answer (score 1):

I had that issue in the past,

here is an example from my project - [LIVE DEMO](https://codverter.com/src/webeditor?query=63631683-8167-40b4-a560-2e3923d31f3d)
drag the editor splitter and watch the reaction of the output.

The trick is in the css:

```
  .general /* the beckground image class */
  {
    background-image: url('https://clipground.com/images/business-people-handshake-clipart-18.png');
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center top;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    opacity: 0.95;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-background-size: cover !important;
    z-index: -1;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
```

Comment: Few years late, but excellent fix! I have the same issue and your code is exactly what I needed. Thank you!